# Show the ten first contacts that I have recieved message

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to create Sql statement that show the ten first contacts that I have recieved message from along with their latest sent message and time. The table columns is `messageId, messageBody, fromUser, toUser, timeStamp` and table is called `messages`. The database is Mysql and Java is the language. But I want this to happen in one single sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interpreting "show the ten first contacts" as the first 10 people that submitted messages.

```
Select M2.fromUser
    , LastMessage.messageBody
    , LastMessage.timeStamp
From    (
        Select M1.fromUser
            , Min(M1.timeStamp) As FirstMessage
            , Max(M1.messageId) As LastMessageId
        From messages As M1
        Where M1.toUser = 'my username'
        Group By M1.fromUser
        Order By Min(M1.timeStamp) Asc
        Limit 10
        ) As M2
    Join messages As LastMessage
        On LastMessage.messageId = M2.LastMessageId
```

Comment: Hi! I tried to implement your code. But I don't quite understand what you're doing with FirstMessage, even though I recieve right result?

Comment: Ok changed I made som changes from min to max instead to make it more intuitive

Comment: @Woho87 - If you mean the accidental use of Min for LastMessageId, yeah that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group by` to find the latest message per contact.  Then you can join back to the message table to retrieve the message body:

```
select  LastTen.Contact
,       LastTen.LastMessageDate
,       msg.messageBody
from    (
        select  fromUser as Contact
        ,       max(timeStamp) as LastMessageDate
        from    YourTable
        where   toUser = 'YourName'
        group by
                fromUser
        order by
                max(timeStamp) desc
        limit 10
        ) LastTen
join    YourTable msg
on      msg.fromUser = lastTen.Contact
        msg.timeStamp = lastTen.LastMessageDate
```

Comment: I don't know who voted you down, but I think this one is clearly the easiest one

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, but I can see why. It doesn't retrieve the messages.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: Cool, I didn't see that myself.  Join added to retrieve the message body.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT fromUser, messageBody, timeStamp
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT fromUser FROM messages ORDER BY timeStamp LIMIT 10) AS m1
       LEFT JOIN messages
         ON(fromUser)
ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What would happen if the first 10 messages submitted were all by the same person?

Comment: Good point. I've modified my example (to correct this, I hope).

Comment: Most DBMS would not be happy with the use of a column in the Order By that isn't in the Select clause when using Distinct. TBH, I'm not really sure how it would interpret that assuming the DB allowed for it.

Comment: didn't you missed the toUser clause?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT fromUser, timeStamp, messageBody FROM messages ORDER BY timeStamp LIMIT 10
```

Comment: That doesn't retrieve the latest sent message and time for each of those users.

Comment: Not so easy while keeping it a single query.

Comment: Can't see why you need left join here. Isn't there only one table involved?

Comment: For each of 10 contacts, you want the result table to have a single row, but the data from that result row in general has to come from two distinct rows of the original table (earliest sent time row and latest sent message row). You have to join those rows somehow.