# SQL: ten first contacts that I have received message from or sent to along with their latest sent message and time

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a follow up to complicated mysql question that I recently asked: [Show the ten first contacts that I have recieved message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146097/show-the-ten-first-contacts-that-i-have-recieved-message)

Now I know that it is missing something, my last question was:

> I want to create Sql statement that
>   show the ten first contacts that I
>   have recieved message from along with
>   their latest sent message and time.
>   The table columns is messageId,
>   message, fromProfileId, toProfileId,
>   timeStamp and table is called
>   messages. The database is Mysql and
>   Java is the language. But I want this
>   to happen in one single sql statement.

What's missing is that I want to show the message I've sent also, but it should be grouped with the messages that I've recieved from the user I've sent to:

> ten first contacts that I have
>   received message from or sent to along
>   with their latest sent message and
>   time.

Little complicated to understand? Ok. think like this. the quoted first sql statement above only show messages that I reveived from. but what if I send a message? That message will never show up.

This is my code, but I failed to succed(look at where I marked the comment):

```
"SELECT M2.messageProfileId, profiles.profileMiniature, profiles.firstName, profiles.lastName, profiles.timeFormat, lastMessages.message, lastMessages.timeStamp " +
            "FROM   (" +
            "       SELECT IF(M1.fromProfileId = ?, M1.toProfileId, M1.fromProfileId) AS messageProfileId, " +
            "           max(M1.timeStamp) AS lastMessageTime " +
            "       FROM messages AS M1 " +
            "       WHERE M1.toProfileId = ? " +
            "       OR M1.fromProfileId = ? " +
            "       GROUP BY IF(M1.fromProfileId = ?, M1.toProfileId, M1.fromProfileId) " +
            "       ORDER BY max(M1.timeStamp) DESC " +
            "       LIMIT 10 " +
            "       ) AS M2 " +
            "INNER JOIN messages AS lastMessages " +
            "ON     (" +
            "       lastMessages.timeStamp = M2.lastMessageTime " +
            "AND    lastMessages.fromProfileId = M2.messageProfileId" +//This to be like the if statements above, but how?
            "       )" +
            "INNER JOIN profiles " +
            "ON M2.messageProfileId = profiles.profileId ";
```

**UPDATE:**

All question marks in the above code will be replaced with a a same id, for example 27.

**UPDATE:**

You just have to solve one line now. Look at the commented line above. I dont know how to make if statement in where clause?

Comment: Is `messageProfileId` the same as `messageId`?

Comment: no messageProfileId is the the profileId the message is relevant to. And profileId is the same as userid, but in this case I call it profileId. By relevant I mean fromProfileId or toProfileId depending on if I received the message or if I sent the message

Comment: messageId is the primary key of messages is like an index only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out myself

```
   "SELECT M2.messageProfileId, profiles.profileMiniature, profiles.firstName, profiles.lastName, profiles.timeFormat, lastMessages.message, lastMessages.timeStamp " +
                "FROM   (" +
                "       SELECT IF(M1.fromProfileId = ?, M1.toProfileId, M1.fromProfileId) AS messageProfileId, " +
                "           max(M1.timeStamp) AS lastMessageTime " +
                "       FROM messages AS M1 " +
                "       WHERE (M1.toProfileId = ? " +
                "       OR M1.fromProfileId = ?) " +
                "       GROUP BY IF(M1.fromProfileId = ?, M1.toProfileId, M1.fromProfileId) " +
                "       ORDER BY max(M1.timeStamp) DESC " +
                "       LIMIT 10 " +
                "       ) AS M2 " +
                "INNER JOIN messages AS lastMessages " +
                "ON     (" +
                "       lastMessages.timeStamp = M2.lastMessageTime " +
                "AND    (" +
                "       lastMessages.fromProfileId = M2.messageProfileId " +
                "OR     lastMessages.toProfileId = M2.messageProfileId " +
                "       )" +
                "       )" +
                "INNER JOIN profiles " +
                "ON M2.messageProfileId = profiles.profileId ";
```